# How can a dynamically-loaded Haskell function be able to import a module contained in a pre-compiled object file who is stored in another directory?

Tags: haskell, dynamic

Suppose the `A` module below. It is dynamically loaded in my system. It imports `DataExec` module.

```
module A where

import DataExec
```

`DataExec` module is used also in the *static* part of my system. So, i have a compiled `.o` file of `DataExec`. It is not located on the directory `A.hs` is. I want `A` module to load this `.o` file in order to use `DataExec`.

Is it possible? How can i do that?

Actually, the `DataExec` module is re-compiled everytime the system dynamically loads `A` module, and a new `DataExec.o` file is created on the same directory of `A.hs`.

When i put `A.hs` and `DataExec.o` in the same directory, it seems that the `.o` file is not re-compilled.

The code i use to dynamically load `A` module is:

```
runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
            dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
            setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { 
                ghcLink   = LinkInMemory, 
                ghcMode = CompManager,
                importPaths   = ["C:\\my_source_path\\"]
                }

            target <- guessTarget ("A.hs") Nothing
            setTargets [target]
            load LoadAllTargets

            importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl $ "import A" 
            setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]          

            value <- dynCompileExpr ("A.getSomething")
```

I have tried to set some `DynFlags`, such as `includePaths` and `libraryPaths`, but a new `DataExec.o` is always created.

Comment: Have you tried setting `importPaths` to include the directory containing `A.hs` and `DataExec.o`?

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, i did it. A runtime error occur: Could not find module DataExec. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i have found is to use `objectDir` and `hiDir` dynamic flags.

The updated code i use to dynamically load `A` module is:

```
runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
            dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
            setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { 
                ghcLink   = LinkInMemory, 
                ghcMode = CompManager,
                objectDir   = Just "C:\\my_source_path\\",
                hiDir   = Just "C:\\my_source_path\\"
                }

            target <- guessTarget ("A.hs") Nothing
            setTargets [target]
            load LoadAllTargets

            importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl $ "import A" 
            setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]          

            value <- dynCompileExpr ("A.getSomething")
```