# How to dynamically compile and import a module using GHC API - LTS Haskell 20.20 (ghc-9.2.7)?

Tags: haskell

**Background**

I would like to implement a program in Haskell that can generate Haskell module (hs-File) dynamically and then compile, and import it into the same application that generated the code.

Therefore, I tried to understand some example code snippets in SO and documentation. But it doesn't work nor compiles.

After some modifications of one of the given examples, I created the following souce code, Main.hs:

```
import qualified GhcApiWrap as Ghw

main :: IO ()
main = Ghw.msLoadModuleAndExecute "../dyn/" "DynExample.hs" "nFromChar" 'A'
```

GhcApiWrap.hs:

```
module GhcApiWrap
    (
        msLoadModuleAndExecute
    ) where

import GHC
--import GHC.Paths (libdir)  

msLoadModuleAndExecute :: String -> String -> String -> Char -> IO ()
msLoadModuleAndExecute _ _ _ _ = do
    value' <- runGhc (Just "./src/") $ do
            dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
            setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { 
                ghcLink   = LinkInMemory, 
                ghcMode = CompManager,
                objectDir   = Just "../dyn/",
                hiDir   = Just "../dyn/"
                }
            target <- guessTarget ("DynExample.hs") Nothing
            setTargets [target]
            ret <- load LoadAllTargets
            case ret of
                Succeeded -> do
                    importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl $ "import DynExample"
                    setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]

                    value <- dynCompileExpr ("DynExample.nFromChar")

                    return value
                _       -> 
                    return undefined
    print $ value'
```

DynExample.hs:

```
module DynExample
    (
        nFromChar
    ) where

nFromChar :: Char -> Int
nFromChar _ = 33
```

...which compiles but doesn't work.

Its ouput is:

```
ExprmntGhcApi-exe: Missing file: src/settings
```

As you can see, I commented out `import GHC.Paths (libdir)` because it doesn't exist anymore. Therefore, as a humble guess I used `(Just "./src/")` instead of `(Just libdir)`.

I tried several versions that are "flying around", but none of them work with GHC 9.2.7.

**Question**

Is it, and how is it possible to use `DynExample.nFromChar` dynamically this way using an up-to-date Haskell Stack environment, and having the following type of the function?

```
msLoadModuleAndExecute :: String -> String -> String -> Char -> ... Int
```

**Environment**

At the moment, I am using Stack with:

```
resolver:
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/20/20.yaml
```

...which translates to usage of GHC 9.2.7.

Comment: Related, reiewd topics:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133433
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790341
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680575
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779143
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806460
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198140
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521129
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228537

Comment: "...which compiles but doesn't work." What it does output?

Comment: @freestle: The output is "ExprmntGhcApi-exe: Missing file: src/settings".

Comment: `dynCompileExpr` returns `Dynamic` object which should be casted to type of your function `Char -> Int` and then calculate.

Comment: Looks like you provide invalid path to GHC location here `runGhc (Just "./src/")`.

Comment: @freestle: That's right. That will be an additional problem. But, at the moment it even doesn't use the file `DynExample.hs`. The types doesn't matter for the given code, at the moment. The `value` seems to be of `class Show`, doesn't it?

Comment: @freestle: I guessed that too. Hence, I looked for a folder or file named `settings` and could't find one. What is the API lookong for?

Comment: "import GHC.Paths (libdir) doesn't exist anymore." Where it says?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254804/discussion-between-jorg-bruggmann-and-freestyle).

Answer (score 2):

So, issue with `import GHC.Paths (libdir)` solved by adding a dependence to the ghc-paths package.

Next issue was with provide correct argument to the `guessTarget`. From the doc:

> Attempts to guess what Target a string refers to. This function implements the --make/GHCi command-line syntax for filenames.

So, need provide path to the module not just the name.

And last problem is that `dynCompileExpr` returns Dynamic object which should be casted to type of your function `Char -> Int` and then calculate.

Combine all together we can get:

```
module GhcApiWrap
    (
        msLoadModuleAndExecute
    ) where

import Control.Exception.Safe
import Data.Dynamic
import GHC
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import System.FilePath

msLoadModuleAndExecute :: FilePath -> FilePath -> String -> Char -> IO Int
msLoadModuleAndExecute buildDir modulePath funcName arg = do
    dynFunc <- runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { ghcLink   = LinkInMemory
                                    , ghcMode   = CompManager
                                    , objectDir = Just buildDir
                                    , hiDir     = Just buildDir
                                    }
        target <- guessTarget modulePath Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        loadStatus <- load LoadAllTargets
        case loadStatus of
            Succeeded -> do
                let moduleName = dropExtension $ takeFileName modulePath
                importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl $ "import " ++ moduleName
                setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]
                dynCompileExpr $ moduleName ++ "." ++ funcName
            Failed    -> throwString $ "could not load the module: " ++ modulePath
    case fromDynamic dynFunc of
        Just func -> pure $ func arg
        Nothing   -> throwString $ funcName ++ " has type '" ++ show dynFunc ++ " but expected type `Char -> Int'"
```

which can be run with:

```
import qualified GhcApiWrap as Ghw

main :: IO ()
main = print =<< Ghw.msLoadModuleAndExecute "../dyn/" "DynExample.hs" "nFromChar" 'A'
```

But I think will be better simplify this function on just `compileAndLoad` that make it more generic.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module GhcApiWrap
    (
        msCompileAndLoad
    ) where

import Control.Exception.Safe
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Typeable
import GHC
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import System.FilePath

msCompileAndLoad :: forall a. Typeable a => FilePath -> FilePath -> String -> IO a
msCompileAndLoad buildDir modulePath symbolName = do
    dynSymbol <- runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { ghcLink   = LinkInMemory
                                    , ghcMode   = CompManager
                                    , objectDir = Just buildDir
                                    , hiDir     = Just buildDir
                                    }
        target <- guessTarget modulePath Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        loadStatus <- load LoadAllTargets
        case loadStatus of
            Succeeded -> do
                let moduleName = dropExtension $ takeFileName modulePath
                importDecl_RdrName <- parseImportDecl $ "import " ++ moduleName
                setContext [IIDecl importDecl_RdrName]
                dynCompileExpr $ moduleName ++ "." ++ symbolName
            Failed    -> throwString $ "could not load the module: " ++ modulePath
    case fromDynamic dynSymbol of
        Just x  -> pure x
        Nothing -> throwString $ symbolName ++ " has type '" ++ show dynSymbol
                 ++ "' but expected type '" ++ show symbolType ++ "'"
  where
    symbolType = typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

Then we can use it:

```
import qualified GhcApiWrap as Ghw

main :: IO ()
main = do
    nFromChar <- Ghw.msCompileAndLoad "../dyn/" "DynExample.hs" "nFromChar"
    print $ (nFromChar :: Char -> Int) 'A'
```

Comment: @K. A. Buhr: Thank you for the edit! It looks like you made it ready for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from *freestyle* and *K. A. Buhr* works.

However, I created an alternative version, which should have the following characteristics:

- not throwing exceptions but forwarding error messages via `Either`
- catching all exceptions to forward its error messages via `Either`
- not modifying the `dflags` if not needed
- avoiding the do notation
- avoiding case constructions
- using qualified imports, where reasonably possible
- describing all necessities including stack setup details
- usage of the module name implying extension “hs” for the file
- hlint free

I tested the code regarding

- function
- unavailability of the module file
  (e.g. "Error: Exception: can't find file: ./dyn/DynExample.hs")
- compiler error regarding the module file
  (e.g. "Error: Could not load the module "DynExample"!")
- error regarding type check vs. imported symbol
  (e.g. "Error: Symbol nFromChar has type "<<Char -> Int>>" but expected type "Char -> Integer"")

**GhcApiWrap**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module GhcApiWrap
    (
        compileAndLoad
    ) where

import qualified Control.Exception.Safe as Exc
import qualified Data.Dynamic as Dyn
import qualified Data.Proxy as Px
import qualified Data.Typeable as T
import qualified GHC as Ghc
import qualified GHC.Paths as Pth
import Data.Functor ((<&>))

compileAndLoad :: forall a. T.Typeable a => String -> String -> String -> IO (Either String a)
compileAndLoad dir mdl sym = runGhcCatched >>= ethSym
  where
    runGhcCatched = Ghc.runGhc (Just Pth.libdir) (loadModule dir mdl sym)
                    `Exc.catchAny`
                    (\ex -> return (Left ("Exception: " ++ show ex)))
    ethSym (Right dynSym) = return (ethSym' (Dyn.fromDynamic dynSym) (sErrFromDynSym dynSym))
    ethSym (Left sErr) = return (Left sErr)
    sErrFromDynSym dynSym = "Symbol " ++ sym ++ " has type \"" ++ show dynSym ++ 
        "\" but expected type \"" ++ show symbolType ++ "\""
    ethSym' (Just dynSym) _ = Right dynSym
    ethSym' Nothing sErr = Left sErr
    symbolType = T.typeRep (Px.Proxy :: Px.Proxy a)

loadModule :: Ghc.GhcMonad m => String -> String -> String -> m (Either String Dyn.Dynamic)
loadModule dir mdl sym = 
        Ghc.getSessionDynFlags >>= 
        Ghc.setSessionDynFlags >> 
        Ghc.guessTarget (dir ++ mdl ++ ".hs") Nothing >>= 
        (\target -> Ghc.setTargets [target]) >> 
        Ghc.load Ghc.LoadAllTargets >>= 
        returnFromLoadStatus
    where
        returnFromLoadStatus Ghc.Succeeded = dynSym <&> Right
        returnFromLoadStatus Ghc.Failed = return (Left ("Could not load the module \"" ++ mdl ++ "\"!"))
        dynSym = Ghc.parseImportDecl ("import " ++ mdl) >>= 
                 (\importDecl -> Ghc.setContext [Ghc.IIDecl importDecl]) >> 
                 Ghc.dynCompileExpr (mdl ++ "." ++ sym)
```

**Usage**

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import qualified GhcApiWrap as Ghw

main :: IO ()
main =  Ghw.compileAndLoad "./dyn/" "DynExample" "nFromChar" >>= 
        (\case 
            (Right nFromChar) -> putStrLn ("nFromChar 'A' := " ++ show ((nFromChar :: Char -> Integer) 'A'))
            (Left sErrorMassage) -> putStrLn ("Error: " ++ sErrorMassage))
```

**Dynamic file to read ("DynExample.hs")**

NOTE: The file has to be located in diretcory `dyn` side by side to the directory `src`, in order to be compatible with the code above ("Usage").

```
module DynExample
    (
        nFromChar
    ) where

import qualified Data.Char as Chr

nFromChar :: Char -> Int
nFromChar = Chr.ord
```

**Output**

```
nFromChar 'A' := 65
```

**package.yaml**

```
...

description:...

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- ghc
- ghc-paths
- safe-exceptions

ghc-options:
...
```

**stack.yaml**

```
...

resolver:
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/20/20.yaml

...
```